# In Rails, can I filter one-to-many relationships without updating the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I am using Rails 5 and I want to be able to filter a one-to-many relationship to only send a subset of the child items to the client.  The data model is pretty standard, and looks something like this:

```rb
class Parent < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :children, class_name: 'Child'
end

class Child < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :parent
end
```

When the client makes a call, I only want to return *some* of the `Child` instances for a `Parent`.

This is also complicated because the logic about which `Child` objects should be returned is absurdly complicated, so I am doing it in Ruby instead of the database.

Whenever I execute something like the following, Rails is attempting to update the database to remove the association.  I don't want the database to be updated.  I just want to filter the results before they are sent to the client.

```rb
parent.children = parent.children.reject { |child| child.name.include?('foo') }
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Add an instance method in `Parent` model

```
def filtered_children
  children.where.not("name like ?", '%foo%')
end
```

Call `filtered_children` wherever required, it doesn't make sense to reset the existing association instance variable. The same queries are cached so it doesn't matter if you call them one time or multiple times. But you can always `memoize` the output of a method to make sure the the method is not evaluated again second time onwards,

```
def filtered_children
  @filtered_children ||= children.where.not("name like ?", '%foo%')
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I am not sure this is going to be usable though.  This will do a whole new query.  This will potentially be called 50+ times.  And I want to avoid 50 round trips to the database.  To avoid this, I am eagerly loading all Parent and Child instances.

Comment: What do you exactly want to achieve, the same queries are cached so it doesn't matter if you call them one time or multiple times. Or you can memoize them to stop being called multiple times, check my edit.

Comment: In reality I have three layers of one-to-many relationships.  I want to eagerly request all of the records (including some extra eager calls).  Then, I would like to filter each level of those results in Ruby code that can be unit tested.

Comment: Some other potential solutions include...
 1. replacing the ActiveRecord::Relation::CollectionsProxy with a simple array.  I have not been able to figure out how to do this.
 2.  Detaching the all of the instances from the database session.  This also seems impossible to do.

Answer (score 0):

DB update is happening because filtered records are being assigned back to `parent.children`. Instead another variable can be used.

`filtered_children = parent.children.reject { |child| child.name.include?('foo') }`

Comment: This will not work because that "reject" function will modify the database.

Comment: @EvilJoe `Reject` function won't remove from db. assigning the remaining objects to `parent.children` will remove from db.

Comment: I am sure that it does because that is what prompted this whole post.  In the end, I had to create new classes & place my model object hierarchy in these "server-side filterable" classes.  Then, I did the filtering from those because they were using regular arrays instead of ActiveRecord proxies.

Comment: Ah, you are correct, but I would like to keep the objects in their current structure (with some of them filtered out).  The structure is complicated and a duplicate of the structure would be fragile to maintain.